# How do i make parallel calls to a service depending on different IF() conditions in a loop?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to make calls to a service which gives some json result. Depending on a few conditions i have to save the response in different objects.
When i use a foreach loop it works fine but it takes a lot of time.
Same code when i use a parallel foreach loop it skips some part of the result.
I have tried using task.WaitAll().
Any suggestions?
P.S. First question on stack overflow.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you are using correctly the Parallel function as you didn't write here any code.

I think that the solution to it is using Parallel.ForEach and you might also update its ParallelOptions and specify the sound of maximum parallelism you wish.

I think you probably didn't use the `WhenAll` method together with the parallel `ForEach` which might be the cause for the problems you faced.

It might be something like:

```
List<Task> tasks = new();

Parallel.ForEach(<source>, new ParallelOptions
   { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = <MAX_DEGREE_OF_PARALLELISM> }, s =>
{
    tasks.Add(<action>);
});

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Note, in order to make the script above work fine you need to provide: `source, MAX_DEGREE_OF_PARALLELISM, action`.